# Symfony error while moving from local environment to shared hosting

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to move my project that is working fine in my local environment onto a live shared hosting platform. None of my content showed up, so I started trying to find the problem. I was getting a 500 error on my bootstrap.php page, so I tracked the error and received this message:

```
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_5b4077feb9bf47a70ccde805100ae624, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /hermes/bosnaweb03b/b700/ipg.briangwaltney/YSC-Main/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php on line 61 Warning: SessionHandler::write(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_5b4077feb9bf47a70ccde805100ae624, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /hermes/bosnaweb03b/b700/ipg.briangwaltney/YSC-Main/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php on line 69
```

I did a bunch of research and found a bunch of old questions suggesting you change the app/config/config.yml file to fix this. That file does not exist in my directory, but config/framework.yml was there, so I made those suggested changes. Here is what that was changed to:

```
framework:
    secret: test
    router: { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/%kernel.test_case%/routing.yml" }
    validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
    assets: ~
    csrf_protection: true
    form: true
    test: ~
    default_locale: en
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

services:
    logger: { class: Psr\Log\NullLogger }
```

That didn't fix it, so I'm totally stuck. I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For ref, here is my bootstrap and autoload files.

bootstrap.php :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/connection.php';



$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$session = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session();
$session->start();
```

vendor/autoload.php:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit1975f3b1eb8deeaabd9c59cc0a28694b::getLoader();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You updated your session.save_path to `"%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"` that means it will place it into `/path/to/your/project/app/sessions`. Usually the app-folder is read only. In the default project structure there is a `var/` directory containing logs and chache files and it also has a folder for sessions. I would suggest using that instead: `"%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions"`. You also have to ensure that the var-directory is writable by your web user (usually www-data). Since you are on a shared hosting environment you might have to log in to your provider's web ui and find a file management tool there. If you still can not get it to work you might want to change the session handler, e.g. to database. using [PDO Session Storage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html) or a [Redis session handler](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#sessions).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed it to the /var/php_sessions folder as that's what it's specifically looking for and it's still not working. I've looked at the permissions and it is set to writable. For some reason, the session still isn't being written. Do you have any other ideas?

We are on the right track; when I comment out the session code, the site works minus the components that require the session of course.

Comment: Sorry, I have no other ideas, everything point to permissions. You could try putting `dump(posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()))` in your script to confirm you set the folder permissions for the right user.

Comment: Thank you for the continued help. The more I look at this the more I'm thinking I'm changing the wrong file. I can't seem to find the app/config/config.yml file. Is that automatically created by Symfony?

Forgive my ignorance. This is my first attempt at this.

Comment: Yes, the config.yml is in your symfony project. I'm guessing that the full path is something like `/var/www/html/app/config/config.yml`. It might also be that you have to clear the cache directory (basically do an `rm -rf /var/www/html/var/*` or run `php bin/console cache:clear` from inside the project root `/var/www/html`).